# Spring Context wildcard in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, spring, maven, classpath

We have a project setup here which uses Maven profiles quite extensively. We're using Spring, and although we mostly have an annotation-based configuration there are a few XML configuration files needed.

These Spring XML config files are pulled in with various different profiles, and in the actual web application they're all put in WEB-INF/spring and loaded up with `classpath:spring/spring-*.xml`. This works fine.

The problem is unit testing: I want to test a variety of different profiles, and Spring seems to have an issue with a wildcard specification like that when the files are spread over several directories.

The easiest solution I think would just be to specify each config file in the `@ContextConfiguration` test annotation, but unfortunately if one is missing Spring throws an exception, and there doesn't seem to be a way of turning this off.

The other thing I thought was potentially dumping all spring config files into one folder before running the tests, but that seems a bit of a kludge.

I was just wondering if anyone else had any experience of this problem and any workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the Spring guys have [thought of this](http://www.gridshore.nl/2008/05/13/spring-application-context-loading-tricks/comment-page-1/) already.

You can use the syntax:

```
classpath*:spring/spring-*.xml
```

Which seems to work properly.

Comment: Yup, it's not their fault, the classloader works that way. See this for reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards